# While using BeautifulSoup4 on Python, why when I try to print the "<p>" element, it results in 'None'?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My code is:

```
html_doc = "file:///C:/Users/Me/Desktop/Convert%20URL%20to%20HTML%20Link.html"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")


print(soup.p)
```

Using other soup.a/p/title, it also results in None, even though I'm sure it there should be any of those elements on the HTML document.

This is the actual URL link to the HTML document: https://www.textfixer.com/html/convert-url-to-html-link.php

Comment: Welcome to SO! What data are you trying to get exactly? `soup` is the entire HTML document, so it won't have a `p` property. You'll need `find` or `find_all` to traverse the HTML tree to locate elements with certain attributes (such as being a `<p>` tag), e.g. `soup.find_all("p")`.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome @ggorlen. I was trying to get all the text in the <p> tag. I tried what you said and changed the `print(soup.p)` to `print(soup.find_all("p"))`. Now all that comes up is []. Did BeautifulSoup finding nothing?

Comment: It seems so. I didn't look at your code carefully, but you're never opening the file, just sticking the path into BS. Open and read the file into a string, then input it into BS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that html is a file in your directory that you have downloaded.

You **must** open the file first, read then scrape:

example as below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

file_dir = "C:/Users/Me/Desktop/Convert URL to HTML Link.html"

with open (file_dir , "r") as files_f:
    content = files_f.read()
files_f.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
selections_p = soup.find_all("p")

print(selections_p )
```

if you are scraping from a website, then you should **request** the page first, then scrape:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with requests.session() as s_request:
    url_to_scrape  = 'https://www.textfixer.com/html/convert-url-to-html-link.php'
    request_page = s_request.get(url_to_scrape)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(request_page.content, 'html.parser')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
    selections_p = soup.find_all("p")
    print(selections_p)
```

Comment: I wouldn't have figured that out, thanks. However, a popup states while highlighting the `with open (file_dir , "r") as files_f:`, Errno 22, invalid argument. Reading some more information, this error means I'm trying to open a directory as a file. How should I open the file and read the file?

Comment: Please, check your file directory in. Check, includes 'slash' and where the html file is located. Directory slash **must** single forward slash "/" or double backslash "\\".